# preg_match_all multi word search

Tags: php, search, preg-match, preg-match-all

Basically I'm trying to use preg_match_all in order to perform a multi search.
I have 3 arrays :

- `$searchWordBis`, which contains the words to be searched.
- `$linkArray`, which contains strings, that's the array I want to search in.
- `$matches`, which will contain the results of the research.

I want each word of $searchWordBis to be searched in $linkArray.

Here is what I wrote :

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($searchWordBis)-1 ; $i++) { //loop test to do the search for each word of $searchWordBis and that way opperate a multi-words search

    $fct = function($var) use ($searchWordBis) { //$fct is a "closure" (anonymous function)
        return preg_match_all("/\b$searchWordBis[$i]\b/i", $var, $pregMatches);
    };
    $matches = array_values(array_filter($linkArray, $fct));    //filtering $matches array according to $fct + reseting index

    /* Tests */
    echo $searchWordBis[$i];
    echo '<br>';

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($pregMatches);
    echo '</pre>';

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($matches);
    echo '</pre>';
    /* ----- */
}
```

But it isn't working. What's wrong in my code ? Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate from where did you get `$searchWordBis[$i]`? What you were getting within it? For what string you were using the following regex

Comment: `"/\b$searchWordBis[$i]\b/i"` should be `"/\b{$searchWordBis[$i]}\b/i"` ? `$i` is not defined in your closure. edit: your code is not formatted correctly. see my proposed change below:

Comment: @Uchiha I thought $searchWordBis[$i] could be used to access to the $i element of the array.

Comment: @KyleDomingo $i is the index of an element of the $searchWordBis array. Forgot to define it in my code !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($searchWordBis)-1 ; $i++) {
    $fct = function($var) use ($searchWordBis, $i) {
        return preg_match_all("/\b{$searchWordBis[$i]}\b/i", $var, $pregMatches);
    };
    $matches = array_values(array_filter($linkArray, $fct));
    ...
```

in your closure, include `$i` in the use clause, and enclose the array in curly braces. OR you can also use `foreach` instead of `for` to avoid counters

```
foreach ($searchWordBis as $pattern) {
    $fct = function($var) use ( $pattern) {
        return preg_match_all("/\b$pattern\b/i", $var, $pregMatches);
    };
    $matches = array_values(array_filter($linkArray, $fct));
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) is more simple

```
$pattern = '~\b(?:' . implode('|', $searchWordBis) . ')\b~S';

$result = preg_grep($pattern, $linkArray);
```

If you want the result for each word:

```
foreach ($searchWordBis as $searchWord) {
    echo $searchWord . PHP_EOL;
    print_r(preg_grep('~\b' . $searchWord . '\b~', $linkArray));
}
```